# Raspberry PI: make command not working with below makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

**Makefile:**

```
module=usb-it950x
EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build
PWD = $(shell pwd)
MACHINE = $(shell uname -m)
KDIR26   := /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/kernel/drivers/media
DEST = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/kernel/$(MDIR)
LMDIR26 := /lib/firmware

usb-it950x-objs := \
        it950x-core.o it950x-drv.o iocontrol.o  \
        tuner.o cmd.o IT9133.o ADF4351.o \
        IT9507.o Omega.o eagleTuner.o \
        standard.o usb2impl.o modulatorUser.o user.o 

obj-m += usb-it950x.o  

default:
    @(cp api/*.* ./; cp src/*.* ./)
    make -s -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

Also, I can compile the makefile at ubuntu.

But, I am trying compile abobe makefile at raspberry pi.

**Error Log:**

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build SUBDIRS=/home/pi/it950x_driver modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

How I can compile this makefile at raspberry pi(raspbian)?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.   Please do not paste screenshots when it can be avoided.   Cut and paste the text as code text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a Makefile at `/lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build` on your pi.   (your initial recipe for `default` runs, but then calls make with a `-C` that points to a directory with no makefile, and your error message comes from that).

Try doing an `ls /lib/modules/`, and see what directories it has in there.   Note that this [web page](http://wiki.lemaker.org/How_to_Compile_driver_on_Board) implies that you have to install the kernel headers onto a pi board manually...

Comment: Thanks for your good answer, There is no makefile in the `/lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build`